# Electron app with multiple tabbed browser windows connecting to https sites

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am trying to create my own version of http://meetfranz.com/ using Electron.

The app should allow up multiple URLs such as https://messenger.com/ and https://gmail.com/ to be visible and have a tabbed interface.

I've tried both generating Webview and BrowserWindow.

- WebView can't seem to load Messenger completely (does not load login)
- BrowserWindow pops out of the main window…

I tried earlier on also with iFrames which was a no-go.

Any ideas on best way to accomplish a tabbed minimal browser interface that allows cookies/https?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    webview {
        display: inline-flex; 
        width: 800px; 
        height: 600px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form">
        <input name="input" placeholder="https://messenger.com/" value="https://messenger.com">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="tabs">
    </div>
    <div class="webviews">
    </div>
    <!--<webview src="https://messenger.com/" autosize="on" nodeintegration="on" disablewebsecurity="on" webpreferences="allowRunningInsecureContent"></webview>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require('./app.js')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView} = require('electron')

app.on('ready', createWindow)

function createWindow(){
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000, 
        height: 600,
        height: 600, 
        "node-integration": "iframe", // and this line
        "web-preferences": {
            "web-security": false,
            "nodeIntegration": false,
        }
    })

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Load a remote URL
    //win.loadURL('https://github.com')

    // Or load a local HTML file
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

    /*win.webContents.session.webRequest.onHeadersReceived({}, (d, c) => {
        if(d.responseHeaders['x-frame-options'] || d.responseHeaders['X-Frame-Options']){
            delete d.responseHeaders['x-frame-options']
            delete d.responseHeaders['X-Frame-Options']
        }
        c({cancel: false, responseHeaders: d.responseHeaders})
    })*/

}

//app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-web-security')
```

**app.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView} = require('electron').remote

let tabs = document.querySelector(".tabs")
let webviews = document.querySelector(".webviews")

document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = function(event){
    //createWebview(form.input.value)
    createBrowserWindow(form.input.value)
    return false;
}

function createWebview(url){

    let webview = new WebView()
    webview.setAttribute("autosize","on")
    webview.setAttribute("nodeintegration","on")
    webview.setAttribute("disablewebsecurity","on")
    webview.setAttribute("webpreferences","allowRunningInsecureContent")
    webview.src = url
    webviews.appendChild(webview)

    let tab = document.createElement("div")
    tab.textContent = url
    tab.target = webview

    tabs.appendChild(tab)

}

function createBrowserWindow(url){

    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, 
        height: 600,
        y: 100,
        x: 100,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            nodeIntegration: false
        }
    })

    win.setMenu(null)

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })

    view = new BrowserView({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false
        }
    })

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Load a remote URL
    win.loadURL(url)

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<webview>` clearly is the way to if you want to have a single window. It's also a lot better than an `<iframe>`, because it's securely isolated from your app and runs in a separate process.

See the docs: https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/

If messenger.com doesn't load properly, this should be the problem you should be addressing (e.g. inspect console messages, network log). Follow your instincts, your first choice was the right one, now it's about making it work.

Comment: Thank you, I have it working. I banged my head against it for a while, and by removing some of the tags I had added on the generated webview even Messenger decided to show itself.

Comment: I'm doing something similar using `webview` but it ends up complicating communication between different views.  Different solutions would be good to hear about

Comment: Electron docs suggest `BrowserView` be used instead of the `WebView` tag. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag